# Xaml Windows Store How to do a graphical interface like the Modern Ui Start Page

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-store-apps, modern-ui

I'm trying to do a Windows Store interface application like the Modern Ui StartPage.

I need to do an interface which contains all the components in 1 Page. 
The navigation should be a swipe to the right or to le left .

Thanks a lot for you help

Comment: A GridView? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465351.aspx

Comment: Hello, just tried the GridView Component and it's exactly what i have searched. Thanks a lot

Comment: Cool, I'll put it up as an answer, so you can accept it if you think it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A `GridView` exhibits the same behaviour as the Start Menu in Windows 8.

- GridView sample: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListViewSimple-d5fc27dd
- WinRT controls catalog: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465351.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your response

Answer (score 0):

In order to replicate the Windows 8 start screen, you need to use the Semantic Zoom control in addition to the Gridview. [Link](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/winrt-step-by-step-tutorial-mvvm-gridview-semanticzoom/) to implement this.

- Semantic Zoom - http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-GridView-grouping-and-8b0bc6a4